# Python library to manipulate MS Word docs which requires no installation

Tags: gratis, library, python, microsoft-word

I would love to use [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but it is only available as a `.wheel`, and requires PIP to install.

For security reasons, our PCs are locked down tight and we can't install. There is also something else going on with the firewall, because I finally figured out that I could use

```
python.exe" -m pip install -U pip wheel docx
```

but that timed out, so I imagine that they are blocking certain kinds of traffic.

Since a `.wheel` file is just a `.zip` with different extension, I could rename it and extract the files, but I don't know where to copy them to, plus there are the dependencies (lxml, which, in turn, has its own dependencies).

So far, this reads like a question for another site, and maybe it will become one. Right now, I just want a Python library, preferably a single file, with instructions to say where to copy it (some central Python directory, or the directory of the script that uses it), so that I can `import <library>` and use it to read/write MS word files (2103 and later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read [there on the official docs](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html) you can install it without using pip.

1. Download python-docx latest version from [here](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/#files)
2. Extract it using 7zip or your favorite tool
3. cd python-docx-{version}
4. python setup.py install

But you need to make sure the dependencies are met, therefore you need to install first [lxml](https://lxml.de/installation.html). I assume youre using windows, you can find prebuild binaries of lxml [here](https://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html).

I know you wrote you cant install things, but your question reads more like youre not able to cant download files through pip.

I havent tested this, but this should lead you to the correct direction

**EDIT**:

I just found out, that there are actually prebuild python wheels available for lxml [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).
You need to download the one, appropriate to your environment (in my case it was `lxml‑4.2.5‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` - I have python 3.7 installed).

- Afterwards copy it to somwhere
- Install it using pip: 
  `pip install C:/dev/pythonTest/lxml-4.2.5-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl`
- Follow 1-4 from above

After doing this steps, I was able to use python-docx.

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000. That ought to do it. We can't install, as in run a standard setup.exxe, and definitely can't do anything that writes to the registry, but I reckon this ought to be doable. Thanks again!

Comment: I chose `libxml2-2.9.3-win32-x86_64` and copied the contents of its `bin` directory to `<python>\plugins\lxml`. Then I ran `4.python setup.py build` (which mind not have been necessary), and `python setup.py install`, as you said, BUT, I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'`, so need to dig deeper. [This page](https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session1/WinLibxml.html) looked promising, but did not help. I also tried copying the binaries of libxml, libxstl and iconv to both my Python plugins & a directory in the Widnwos PATH. No luck :-(

Comment: Do you have pip installed? I know you cant install from internet, but do you have it installed?

EDIT: I have updated my answer. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000. I found a `pip.tgz` and managed to install it.

Comment: Its also bundled usually with the latest python installation :) Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Yaya!! It workzes! I have opened a 200 point bounty which I can't award for 23 hours. Rest assured that you will receive it then :-)  Thanks a 1,000,000 for your help, and for your patience